# Find the first instance of a character, then work backwards

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to find the 1st instance of something, then work "backwards" using Regex...

I have some strings where a product code is combined with a product name. Unfortunately, the delimiter (a dash) separating the product code from the product code is the same.

The product code can have different numbers of delimiters. Some product codes have one dash, while others might have multiple dashes.

But, I know that *all* product names have a space.

So taking these two strings, for example:

- "ABC-ER-015-30-NEW YORK TWO-TONE EARRINGS"
- "ABC-1234-CALIFORNIA CUSTOM PRODUCT"

I'd like to do the equivalent of:

- Find the first space...
- Then work backwards to find the last dash...
- Then extract everything *before* that dash...

So what I want to extract from the above 2 examples:
- "ABC-ER-015-30"
- "ABC-1234"

This works if there are no dashes in the Item Name:

```
(.*)-
```

But if there is a dash in the Item Name, it captures part of the Item Name.

I feel like there's something really simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use match 1+ uppercase chars and repeat matching a dash and 1+ uppercase chars.

As you `know that all product names have a space`, you could add a positive lookahead asserting a dash, 1+ non whitespace chars followed by a space.

```
^[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+(?=-\S+ )
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times A-Z0-9
- `(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching `-` and A-Z0-9
- `(?=-\S+ )` Positive lookahead, assert `-`, 1+ non whitspace chars and a space

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vnOb2A/1)

Another option is to make use of a capturing group instead of a positive lookahead

```
^([A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+)-\S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sXKgOd/1)

Comment: ++ for simple non-lookahead solution

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?:[A-Z0-9]+-?)+?(?=-\S+[ ])
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6tj634/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```
^               # Beginning of the string.
(?:             # Start of a non-capturing group.
    [A-Z0-9]+   # Any uppercase letter or a digit repeated one or more times.
    -?          # An optional hyphen characters.
)               # End of the non-capturing group.
(?=             # Start of a positive Lookahead.
    -           # Matches a hyphen character literally.
    \S+         # Any non-whitespace character repeated one or more times.
    [ ]         # Matches a space character.
)               # End of the lookahead.
```

---

### References:

- [Lookaheads and Lookbehinds.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: That breakdown is fantastic. I'm a beginner with regex so that helps a lot. Thanks!